# kotlinx-serialization @Serializable not being applied to module

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I have a simple usage of `Serializable` on a data class

```
@Serializable
data class Message(
    val type: String,
    val topics: List<String>,
    val content: String
)
```

but the IDE shows the following warning

```
kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this annotation would not be processed. Make sure that you've setup your buildscript correctly and re-import project.
```

At runtime I receive

```
Serializer for class 'Message' is not found.
Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.
```

I've read countless other StackOverflow posts where the issue is incorrect setup in their `build.gradle.kts`, but I'm triple checked that I'm importing the plugin and dependency. Below is my `build.gradle.kts`

```
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
    id("io.ktor.plugin") version "2.3.2"
}

group = "com.ryandyoon"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("com.ryandyoon.ApplicationKt")

    val isDevelopment: Boolean = project.ext.has("development")
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-websockets:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
}
```

If it makes a difference, yes I am using this in a ktor project, but I'm simply calling

```
Json.decodeFromString<Message>(messageString)
```

Comment: And this error occurs when you execute `./gradlew run` (or `gradle run` if you're not using the Gradle Wrapper)?

Comment: I was directly running with the play button in IntelliJ. Just tried running via `./gradlew run` and I no longer get the issue! Thank you very much for revealing this to me, though can you help me understand why the difference between the two run methods?

Comment: Then it sounds like IntelliJ wasn't running your project correctly. You should have it delegate to the Gradle `run` task. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-gradle.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-tasks.html

Answer (score 9):

I was able to resolve the warning "kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this annotation would not be processed. Make sure that you've setup your buildscript correctly and re-import project." by adding the serialization plugin in the **project**-level build.gradle.kts, and then applying it in the **module**-level build.gradle.kts.

Project build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    ...    
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

Module build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    ...
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}
...
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After commenting out
`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.22' apply false`
from project.gradle, its worked for me and can also able to call

```
SomeClassName.serializer()
```

build.gradle (project)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.5.21'}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
id 'kotlinx-serialization'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'}


dependencies {

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.4.1'}
```